# Pytorch ResNet152 Model Not Predicting

Tags: machine-learning, error-handling, pytorch, resnet, torchvision

I have a Pytorch `resnet152` model, initialized with the following:

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet152()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("resnet152_weights.pth"))

for parameter in model.parameters():
    parameter.requires_grad = False

model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(2048, 10)
```

And "resnet152_weights.pth" contains the weights of the model, which is the exact same as `torchvision.models.ResNet152_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2`. I downloaded it because my IDE (Pycharm) could not find the URL.
When my model is trained, the code `output = model(images)` returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep_learning_model.py", line 184, in <module>
    main()
  File "deep_learning_model.py", line 168, in main
    model = train(model, 2)
  File "deep_learning_model.py", line 141, in train
    output = model(images)
  File "torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "torchvision\models\resnet.py", line 285, in forward
    return self._forward_impl(x)
  File "torchvision\models\resnet.py", line 268, in _forward_impl
    x = self.conv1(x)
  File "torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 463, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Byte but found Float
```

Can you please help me fix this bug (if you want me to send more code, please specify which block).

Comment: Can you try changing `output = model(images)` to `output = model(images.byte())`?

Comment: Tell us the error message, don't just say "it didn't work."

Comment: @Sean exact same error